# Does CASE expression evaluate all cases before processing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN 'Sara' like '% %' THEN SUBSTRING('Sara', 1, CHARINDEX(' ', 'Sara') - 1)
    ELSE 'Sara'
END AS FirstName,
CASE 
    WHEN 'Sara' like '% %' THEN SUBSTRING('Sara', CHARINDEX(' ', 'Sara') + 1, 8000)
    ELSE ''
END AS LastName
```

Pretty straight-forward - I'm testing a name split query. So I test the scenario where the name has no spaces and I get the following exception:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the `SUBSTRING` function.

Why is that? Should it *not* evaluate the first clause and immediate go to the `ELSE`? How do I get around this..?

Comment: 1) Case expression, not case statement. 2) Probably answer is NO. At least not logically. (Implementation is product specific.)

Comment: You do realise you're comparing the literal string `'Sara'` and not a field, right?

Comment: Then why would it throw an exception with substring? I'm a bit confused..

Comment: @Siyual - Yes, I am using it as a test scenario.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, it works fine. What data are you getting issues with?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your query doesn't make much sense. Add sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: @RichBenner - That exact query is not working for me when I run it. I'm not using an existing data set, I'm just taking the literal string 'Sara' and plugging it in to see if it works.

Comment: You know that your first-/last-name split isn't correct even if it would "work"? Firstname is `"Sarah Jessica"` and lastname is `"Parker"` not `"Jessica Parker"`. You should fix it by asking for the first- and last-name explicitly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I just tried the answer (below) and plugged in Sarah Jessica Parker and got FirstName = 'Jessica' and LastName = 'Sarah Parker'. This is what I expect (even if not necessarily situationally correct).

Comment: @user2124871: it's not only situationally incorrect but in general. Its just a wuild guess, actually the firstname and/or the lastname could be a double name or even more. You simply don't know, maybe it's also just the first- or last-name that was provided and you are trying to split it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter understood. That's an entirely different problem for me - I was more curious about this scenario and why the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Optimizer is smart enough to notice you have constant expression there and try to evaluate it. Passing the constant through a variable would trick it to run:

```
DECLARE @TestString nvarchar(100) = 'Sara';

SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN @TestString like '% %'
        THEN SUBSTRING(@TestString, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @TestString) - 1)
        ELSE @TestString
    END AS FirstName,
    CASE 
        WHEN @TestString like '% %'
        THEN SUBSTRING(@TestString, CHARINDEX(' ', @TestString) + 1, 8000)
        ELSE ''
    END AS LastName
```

To answer the question, Processor would calculate `THEN` expression only if `WHEN` is *true*, otherwise it will calculate only `ELSE` expression. But even before that Optimizer would try to substitute all constant expressions with calculated values so that Processor won't have to re-calculate them for each row. It's called "[Constant Folding](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175933(v=sql.105).aspx)".

Comment: Ah. So when the optimizer sees a static/constant value, it determines that the comparative expression 'like' has already been evaluated?

Comment: It is trying to substitute the expression with calculated value so that processor won't have to re-calculate it for each row.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the information - appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

Using a variable works;

```
DECLARE @NameString varchar(10); SET @NameString = 'Sara'

SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN @NameString like '% %' THEN SUBSTRING(@NameString, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @NameString) - 1)
    ELSE @NameString
END AS FirstName,
CASE 
    WHEN @NameString like '% %' THEN SUBSTRING(@NameString, CHARINDEX(' ', @NameString) + 1, 8000)
    ELSE ''
END AS LastName
```

The issue with your code is that it checks that each part will work when a static value is passed. It doesn't like that `CHARINDEX(' ', 'Sara') - 1` resolves to equal -1. A hack to get around this would be to wrap this function in the `ABS()` function;

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN 'Sara' like '% %' THEN SUBSTRING('Sara', 1, ABS(CHARINDEX(' ', 'Sara') - 1))
    ELSE 'Sara'
END AS FirstName,
CASE 
    WHEN 'Sara' like '% %' THEN SUBSTRING('Sara', CHARINDEX(' ', 'Sara') + 1, 8000)
    ELSE ''
END AS LastName
```

Comment: Very well explained - Between the two answers, I understand what is happening now. Thanks for the info.